# OpenGL odd z-axis behaviour when drawing square

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm a newcomer to OpenGL and I was playing around with drawing triangles with different z-coordinates. From what I understand, the z axis point out of the screen, and the -z axis points into the screen.

When I draw a square with 3 corners at a 0.0 z-coordinate, and the last corner at, say, -3.0 z-coordinate, I get this:

[image: wat]

I don't understand how it's making this shape... I thought it would be something like this, since the 4th vertex is just 'far away'.

[image]

Can someone explain?

**Edit:** This is my vertex data

```
// vertex array
float vertices[] = {
    -0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // top left, first 3 are location, last 3 are color
     0.5f,  0.5f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // top right
    -0.5f, -0.5f,  -2.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // bottom left
     0.5f, -0.5f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f // bottom right
};

// element buffer array
GLuint elements[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 1, 3
};
```

And I am calling the draw like:

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
```

Comment: What kind of projection are you using, and what's are your clipping planes set to? (Although I don't think either of those would make your square look like an L-shape)

Comment: I'm applying no transformations to the vertices. All I'm doing is passing the raw vertex data into the shaders, and then using that program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you've just begun learning OpenGL. The problem is that any value not belonging to the range [-1, 1] is simply "out of bounds". All values are normalized in OpenGL. This improves portability. Just think that the whole world(if you're familiar with game development) is a cube of side 2 units. Any further and you're somewhere else entirely. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Chara No problem! Just ask whenever you want some help!